# Error Passing Variable to SQL Server Query Python

Tags: python, sql-server

```
            cursor.execute(""" if exists ( SELECT * from Alert where alert = ? and date = ? and devicename = ? )
                BEGIN
                update Alert set alert = ? where alert = ? and date = ? and devicename = ?
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Alert (alert,date,devicename) VALUES (?, ?, ?) """, row[1], row[0], filename[:-4],
                           row[1], row[1], row[0], filename[:-4], row[1], row[0], filename[:-4])
            cursor.commit()
```

The above code is my sql query for SQLServer. It works if I replace the ? with value but if I do it this way, I receive error. Need help. I am using pyodbc library btw.

> cursor.execute(""" if exists ( SELECT * from Alert where alert = ? and date = ? and devicename = ? )
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: Recommended reading: [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing a *tuple* of 10 parameters as the second parameter to `cursor#execute()`:

```py
sql =  """IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Alert WHERE alert = ? AND date = ? AND devicename = ?)
          BEGIN
              UPDATE Alert SET alert = ? WHERE alert = ? AND date = ? AND devicename = ?
          END
          ELSE
          BEGIN
              INSERT INTO Alert (alert, date, devicename) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
          END """
params = (row[1], row[0], filename[:-4], row[1], row[1], row[0], filename[:-4],
          row[1], row[0], filename[:-4])
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried this but the same error occurs.

Comment: You were also missing an `END` for the insert block.  Try adding that, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Also note that it appears that you want upsert functionality on SQL Server.  Try researching for this for a possibly easier way.

Answer (score 0):

As I note in the comments, I would suggest not using an `EXISTS` to check if the row exists, but instead, check if the `UPDATE` actually *updated* anything. This means that you only need to run a query against the table `dbo.Alert` once if you *do* `UPDATE` the table. You can read more about it here: [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) This also lowers the number of parameters you need to pass.

As for the error, this isn't because of the lack of tuples; you can pass parameters outside of a tuple if you want, and the problem is purely due to your lack of an `END`. You don't, however, actually need the `BEGIN`/`END` here, as you are only running a single statement, so this can shortened to the following:

```py
cursor.execute("""UPDATE dbo.Alert WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) SET alert = ? WHERE alert = ? AND date = ? and devicename = ?;
                  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
                      INSERT INTO dbo.Alert (alert,date,devicename) VALUES (?, ?, ?);""", row[1], row[1], row[0], filename[:-4], row[1], row[0], filename[:-4])
cursor.commit()
```

Though your parameters also seem wrong here. You want to `UPDATE` the value of `alert` to `row[1]` when `alert` has the value `row[1]`. If this is true then the row will be `UPDATE`d with it's *own* value, and if it isn't a *new* row will be `INSERT`ed; something isn't right there as the `UPDATE` is pointless. Perhaps `alert = ?` shouldn't be in the `WHERE` (which means you'll need to lower the number of parameters in `cursor.execute` too.

You might be better off, to avoid repetition of parameters, to define variables in your SQL and pass the values to those. Something like this (data types are guessed):

```py
cursor.execute("""DECLARE @alert int = ?, @date date = ?, @Devicename varchar(20) = ?;
                  UPDATE dbo.Alert WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) SET alert = @alert WHERE alert = @alert AND date = @date and devicename = @devicename;
                  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
                      INSERT INTO dbo.Alert (alert,date,devicename) VALUES (@alert, @date, @devicename);""", row[1], row[0], filename[:-4])
cursor.commit()
```

Answer (score -2):

Use String Formatting such as

```py
sql = "select col1,col2 from DB where col1 >= {} AND col2 <= {}".format(val1,val2)"
```

which outputs

```bash
>>> val1,val2=100,200
>>> sql = "select col1,col2 from DB where col1 >= {} AND col2 <= {}".format(val1,val2)
>>> sql
'select col1,col2 from DB where col1 >= 100 AND col2 <= 200'
```

here's a quick link on how to customize parameters and set their orders
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-format-method/